# How to use "or" on scopes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Trying to use `or` with scopes but it doesn't seem to work.

`first_20` returns a relation, but when I use or, it complains that it returns an array, and throws an error. In most of the examples I can find, it is done exactly like I have it.

```
 scope :first_20, -> {
    first(20)
  }

 scope :starred, ->(list_or_urls) {
   where(url: list_or_urls)
 }
```

then later call it..

`Org.first_20.or(starred(urls))`

Getting a

```
ArgumentError (You have passed Array object to #or. Pass an ActiveRecord::Relation object instead.)
 Org.first_20.or(starred(list_or_urls))
```

How is it possible to use `or` with scopes?

Comment: FWIW and according to the [docs](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#passing-in-arguments), "Using a class method is the preferred way to accept arguments for scopes."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `first_20` scope, use the following query instead to return a `ActiveRecord::Relation`, `first(20)` returns an `Array` instead of `relation`, that's what your error tells

```
scope :first_20, -> { limit(20).order('id ASC') }
```

and, since `starred` is a class method, you need to call it on  `Org` class.

```
Org.first_20.or(Org.starred(urls))
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks! One issue I'm seeing is `Relation passed to #or must be structurally compatible. Incompatible values: [:order, :limit]`

Answer (score 2):

I agree with `Rajdeep's` answer it will definitely work, following is another way of doing it

```
scope :first_20_or_starred, ->(list_or_urls) { first_20.or(starred(list_or_urls)}
```

& then

```
Org.first_20_or_starred
```